# Percentile Rank of values from one data frame vs. another data frame without merging

Tags: r

Suppose we have two data frames

```
df1 <- tibble(name = c("J1","J2","J3","J4","J5","J6","J7","J8","J9","J10"), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
             group = c("group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1"))

df2 <- tibble(name = c("k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6","k7","k8","k9","k10"), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                 group = c("group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1"))
```

I am looking to use a for loop, or any other method recommended, to find the percentile rank of each individual value in df1, by group, relative to df2. I do not want to completely merge df1 and df2 and then find the percentile ranks. I then want to have a new column in df1 that shows said percentile ranks. I do not want to actually alter df2 in any way, just use it as my dataset to find percentile ranks for each value of df1. I am only interested in gathering the percentile ranks of each value in df1.

Is this possible? My thought was to use a for loop to "add" in each iteration from df1 one at a time to df2, find the percentile rank, and then "remove" it from df2, then have all of those percentile ranks in a column.

This is possible in Excel, using the PERCENTILERANK.INC function, but I'd like to do this in R.

I tried the following but am getting a blank output.

```
test <- for (i in df1$name) {
  merge(df1,df2) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(percentile_rank = rank(value)/length(value))
  }
```

Comment: Implementation aside, that would mean classifying one sample (df1) with percentiles calculated from another sample (df2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data aren't too big, you can summarize `df2` so that each entry in the `value2` column (below) is a list of all values for that group, then you can merge it with `df1`.  Each entry in the `value2` column is all the values that could be used to compare each entry in `value`.  Then you can find the percentile as the number of observations in `value2` below `value`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(name = c("J1","J2","J3","J4","J5","J6","J7","J8","J9","J10"), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
              group = c("group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1"))

df2 <- tibble(name = c("k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6","k7","k8","k9","k10"), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
              group = c("group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1","group2","group3","group1"))



df1 %>% left_join(
  df2 %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(value2 = list(value)) ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pctile = mean(value2 < value)) %>% 
  select(-value2)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(group)`
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    name  value group  pctile
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 J1        1 group1  0    
#>  2 J2        2 group2  0    
#>  3 J3        3 group3  0    
#>  4 J4        4 group1  0.25 
#>  5 J5        5 group2  0.333
#>  6 J6        6 group3  0.333
#>  7 J7        7 group1  0.5  
#>  8 J8        8 group2  0.667
#>  9 J9        9 group3  0.667
#> 10 J10      10 group1  0.75
```

Alternatively, you could just save the values for each group in `df2` and then access them by using the `group` variable in `df1` as the index.

```r
df2_vals <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  group_split() 
names(df2_vals) <- sapply(df2_vals, function(x)x$group[1])
df2_vals <- df2_vals %>% purrr::map(~.x %>% select(value) %>% pull)

df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pctile = mean(df2_vals[[group]] < value)) 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    name  value group  pctile
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 J1        1 group1  0    
#>  2 J2        2 group2  0    
#>  3 J3        3 group3  0    
#>  4 J4        4 group1  0.25 
#>  5 J5        5 group2  0.333
#>  6 J6        6 group3  0.333
#>  7 J7        7 group1  0.5  
#>  8 J8        8 group2  0.667
#>  9 J9        9 group3  0.667
#> 10 J10      10 group1  0.75
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me and is a great solution. If I could ask a follow-up, do you mind walking me through a similar code for a Z-score? Essentially the same idea - getting a z score for each value in df1 relative to df2, without adding in any df1 values to df2.

Comment: @JordanPennella Sure, in the first version of the code, replace `  mutate(pctile = mean(value2 < value))` with `mutate(z = (value - mean(value2))/sd(value2))` and in the second version, replace `mutate(pctile = mean(df2_vals[[group]] < value))`  with `mutate(z = (value  - mean(df2_vals[[group]]))/sd(dv2_vals[[group]]))`

Comment: Thank you again. So helpful. Last question: is there a way to do these two (z score and percentile rank) without "adding" in the df1 values to the df2 values when taking the zscore/percentile rank? Meaning, the df1 value does not alter the df2 dataset in any way when taking the values. Let me know if that doesn't make sense. Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: In both of the examples above, the df1 values are not considered when calculating the percentile or z-statistic, only the df2 values.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. I just validated the math on the back-end. Thanks again for all of your help!